# Escaping # in cmd line argument

Tags: ruby, command-line

I have a simple Ruby program which takes the command line arguments and posts them to a server.

However, I want to be able to write the # (pound, hash symbol) in my arguments without ruby trying to parse it. I'm not so familiar with Ruby. I know I can pass the arg with quotes, but I would like to know if it's possible without them.

```
ARGV.each do |a|
    s = '' + a
    puts "Argument: #{s}"
end
```

The above doesn't work. Maybe something with gsub?

Comment: Works Ok for me - in fact you don't even need the 's' variable.  What is it about that which doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps you have problems with your shell interpreting # as a comment. Prepend it with backslash in order to reach Ruby script: `ruby test.rb foo \# bar`

Comment: It was indeed my shell, thanks! I'm building a timesheet web application and wanted to have a commandline script feeding the activities, so I can just type 'ts @customerx #development on application #storm'. A bit like twitter messages. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161590/how-do-you-track-your-time/161883#161883

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like this

```
puts "Argument: ##{s}"
```

`#`is special in `" "` only when it meets  `{}`. Otherwise, it shows `#`.

Comment: On my (Windows) system, that just displays two hashes: 'Argument: ##himum'